# Is it possible to use SQLite database inside a web application

Tags: java, ajax, sqlite, servlets

Since I am new to web application developments, please bear for my silly question.

I am having a scenario wherein the web application want to have a SQLite database inside it.

Also need to access the database with the help of an servlet class/ajax request

I am not sure, its possible or not. please advise me

1. Is it possible to have a sqlite database inside a application
2. Id Yes,is it possible to access the same via servlet/ajax request
3. If yes, is the database will be locally available at client side or not.

Please help me ....!! thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. yes
2. access the DB via servlet = bad practice; access it via your java code
3. the DB is local to the server side not the client, it is not something like HTML5 webstorage